# What is a use case for a generic constructor?

Tags: java, generics, constructor

Consider the following constructor for the class `Foo` (which for the sake of clarity is *not* a generic class):

```
public <T> Foo(T obj) { }
```

This is valid syntax for constructors, just like with normal [generic methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

But what is the use of this syntax? Typically generic methods provide type safety for their return type, and can benefit from type inference by the compiler. For example:

```
Pair<String, Integer> stringInt = Pair.of("asfd", 1234);
```

But a call to a constructor always returns an instance of its declaring class, so its type parameters have no effect on the return type. The constructor above could just be replaced with its [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

```
public Foo(Object obj) { }
```

Of course generics aren't only about type safety for return types. The constructor might just want to constrain the type of argument(s) being passed in. However, the above reasoning still applies for a bounded type parameter:

```
public <N extends Number> Foo(N number) { }

public Foo(Number number) { } //same thing
```

Even nested type parameters with bounds are handled using wildcards:

```
public <N extends Number, L extends List<N>> Foo(L numList) { }

public Foo(List<? extends Number> numList) { } //same thing
```

So what is a legitimate use case for having a generic constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible one, adapted from functional programming.  Suppose we have a `Stream` type that has some internal state, repeatedly yielding new elements until it returns `null`.  The outside callers don't care what the internal state type of the stream type is, so you might get something like

```
class Stream<E> {
  <S> Stream(S initialState, StepFunction<E, S> stepFun) {
    ...
  }
}
```

without the recipient having to know what the internal state type is.

Comment: +1, this is a great example, although it cheats a bit because OP specifically says the enclosing type is not generic. (`Stream<E>` would be generic.)

Comment: @JohnFeminella - I only meant that my specific example `Foo` wasn't generic, just to avoid confusion. I didn't mean it as a restriction on answers.

Comment: I understood the OP's question to be asking about constructors that took generic arguments other than the class's type.

Comment: For reference, a Haskell programmer would recognize this immediately as existentially quantifying `S`; the direct inspiration is [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Fusion-Stream-Monadic.html#t:Stream).

Comment: I don't think this example is correct. In order for this class to work as you described and be type-safe, it must store a "state" data member that involves the type `S`. Thus, `S` must be a type parameter of the class.

Comment: I can think of a way that what you described can be done, but it involves some extra helper classes to wrap the two pieces of data and inheritance to hide the type. But it would seem like an unnecessarily complicated and inefficient way to code such a class.

Answer (score 5):

One thing I can think off of the top of my head is that you can ensure that bounds are fulfilled in the same way across multiple parameters.

Take an obviously stupid and contrived but valid constructor that copies a list from a source to a target:

```
public <T> Foo (List<T> listA, List<T> listB) {
    listA.addAll(listB);
}
```

Using wildcards here would quickly become pretty nasty and probably not do what you want anyway.  It would also be a totally arbitrary restriction to disallow it.  So it makes sense to me that the language spec allows it.

Comment: Or use `T` within body: `<T> Foo(List<T> ts) { T t0 = ts.get(0); ts.set(0, ts.get(1)); ts.set(1, t0); }`. Okay, not a convincing example.

Answer (score 2):

One use case that I can think of is when you want to constrain a constructor argument to more than one type. Only the generic syntax allows you to declare a constructor taking a `List` of `Number`s that also implements `RandomAccess`:

```
public <L extends List<? extends Number> & RandomAccess> Foo(L raNumList) { }

...

Foo f1 = new Foo(new ArrayList<Integer>());
Foo f2 = new Foo(new LinkedList<Integer>()); //compiler error
```

Comment: Or for backward compatibility with pre-generic code, where `Foo` took an `Object`, but now you want something a bit more specialised. `<T extends Object & Comparable<>> Foo(T obj)`. / Not really convinced any of this is at all common.

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce certain constraints for the constructor parameters. E.g. the following code requires two parameters which implement the interfaces InterfaceA and InterfaceB.

```
<T extends InterfaceA & InterfaceB > Foo(T t1, T t2) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main use is to ensure that type constraints are met between multiple parameters. Here's an example that puts a bunch of components on an assembly line in the right order:

```
public <T> AssemblyLine(T[] starting, List<T> components) {
  T[] a = components.toArray(starting);
  Arrays.sort(a);
  this.conveyorBelt.add(a);
}
```

Here the `<T>` ensures that `T[]` and `List<T>` hold the same type `T`, and not (say), `Integer[]` and `List<string>`.

Comment: +1 I forgot about generic arrays and the need to pass an instance, etc. - nice one (I think there's a typo though - it should be `components.toArray`)